# How to update $scope on submit from modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have the following code (I couldn't put all the code here as it is quite large, so I've extracted only what's relevant for this question).

I can add items (through a separate form I have elsewhere that's calling `addItem()` on `ng-submit`) and list them on the page. When I click on the Edit button, next to each item, this opens up a modal panel with the information of the current item. But as I change the values, they're automatically updated on the $scope because of the two-way data binding.

What I'm trying to achieve is that the current item and $scope are only updated when I submit the form (by clicking the submit button), this way I can also click on the Cancel button and abort the operation. I'm guessing some sort of `Update` function, but not sure what to put in there.

Also, I'm repeating one modal for each item in items, but I don't think it's best practice. Any suggestion on how to optimize that is welcome.

Third part of my question is, how do I show the ng-model item.color as "selected" from the list of options when the modal loads?

JS

```
$scope.colors = [
  "blue",
  "green",
  "red"
];

$scope.items = [
  {
   name: "apple",
   color: "red"
  },
  {
   name: "pear",
   color: "green"
  }
];

$scope.addItem = function (itemName,itemColor) {
  $scope.items.push({
    name: itemName,
    color: itemColor
  });
};

$scope.editItem = function () {
  ???
};
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{{$index}} - {{item.name}} - {{item.color}}</span>
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemEditModal{{$index}}">
      Edit
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade" ng-repeat="item in items" id="itemEditModal{{$index}}">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form ng-submit="editItem(item)">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.color" ng-options="color in colors">
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you aren't too deep into project is best to get rid of bootstrap.js and use `angular-ui-bootstrap`. Resolves most of your questions and won't require much markup changes. Otherwise you will need to write directives yourself for implementing various bootstrap.js components

Answer (score 0):

I will start with the second point of your question which is creating a separate modal for each item. Yes that is a bad practise simply put imagine having a large number of items. Too much of anything is not good.

Back to the first part, What I would do is:

- When you click the edit button, add a logic that saves the selected item in a temporary $scope variable, and bind that to the modal. You know as the currently selected item for editing. Clear that variable on submitting the form and on closing the modal.
- Do the necessary changes and tap submit. Here is where you can do either a loop on the items array, when the indexed item matches the id in the temporary scope variable, replace its values with the updated temporary scope. This will show the updated item in the repeater.

Can you please elaborate on the third part of your question as I failed to understand what you need. Are you implying something related to css?

Comment: Thanks. The third part refers to a <select><option></select> tag, if you add the "selected" attribute to an <option> tag, that will be pre-selected from the list by default.